# Expresso Store - Random products

Tags: expresso

is there a way to show a random product using Expresso Store?  The product tag seems to require entry_id="{entry_id}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just need to wrap the product tag in a channel entries tag with `orderby="random"` and whatever limit you wanted. Something along the lines of:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" orderby="random" limit="5"}
 {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}"}
  {title}
  You other fields 
 {/exp:store:product}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for help, that worked perfectly.